# How to get a indented subsubsection with a run-in title?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, subsection

I've tried the follwing:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

But if I do `\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\hspace{3em}\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}` it throws an error

[image]

Comment: change sub to subsub?

Comment: @user202729 you are right. But that didn't fix the issue. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{} 
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}
  {1em}% left
  {3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}% before
  {1em}% after
```

[image]

Comment: Alright. Next time remember to write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.